# Why can't I nest a block tag inside an if tag?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, tags

I have a master template file called `base.html`, in it I have the following code:

```
{% ifequal environment "dev" %}
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
{% endifequal %}
```

I inherit this in other templates and do the following:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link ... >
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is, the stylesheet I link never gets applied, the stylesheets block seems to be ignored whether the ifequal condition is met in the base or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is no longer relevant - as of [r12655](https://github.com/django/django/commit/755a0f6d96) you **can** nest a block tag within a conditional.

Comment: +1 I can probably figure out workaround to make it an if block.  I may try to build a patch too.

Comment: This is no longer true nor relevant. The answer below is correct.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088222/calling-block-inside-an-if-condition-django-template

Answer (score 18):

### Edit (14th October, 2010):

*The original question title is no longer true, according to [this comment](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10975#comment:6) on a ticket on Django.*

#### Original Answer:

I'm not sure why not, but you could just do:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% ifequal environment "dev" %}
        ... something ....
    {% else %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endifequal %}
{% endblock %}
```

Having rethought this a bit - I guess that means repeating that logic inside each of your templates, which is fairly unsatisfactory, but I'll leave this answer here anyway. I've had a quick look through the Django tickets and can't find anything relevant.