# what happen with this django-template if tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

Sorry if I am being a moron, but what happen with this if tag ?

view return:

```
return render_to_response('productos/por_estado.html', {'productos':productos}, 
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
#Im not returning 'estado' !
```

template:

```
{% if estado %}
{% block activos_active %}class="active"{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

template html result:

```
class="active"
```

:S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block tags cannot be set conditionally, arguably because they are part of template inheritance.  I believe this was an explicit design decision by the Django developers.  See [this Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10975) as well as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942797/why-cant-i-nest-a-block-tag-inside-an-if-tag) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: so I'll have to do something tricky to set "class="active"
" of another way. thanks 4 your quickly reply.

Answer (score 1):

One way to set `class="active"` could be just this

```
<div{% if estado %} class="active"{% endif %}>....</div>
```