# Calling block inside an if condition: django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been trying to call a block inside an if condition in django template.

I have a `base template`. I have many other templates that extend the base template.
I have defined a block in base template:

```
{% block test_block %}Test{% endblock %}
```

I then want to override this block on a certain condition in the other templates. If the condition fails, the block shouldn't get overridden. This is something what I have written:

```
{% if test_value %}{% block test_block %}Development{% endblock %}{% endif %}
```

This actually (or may be virtually) ignores the if condition.

**What I finally did:**

```
{% block test_block %}{% if test_value %}Development{% else %}{{ block.super }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

I had to do something like this everywhere it was required.

Is this the best way? Is this the only way? Why can't I try the first way of mine? Or is there any mistake from my side?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942797/why-cant-i-nest-a-block-tag-inside-an-if-tag

Comment: Thanks I've been beating my head over this for hours

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't made a mistake - template blocks are included regardless of any conditionals around them. You can see this from this line of the `ExtendsNode` class of `django/template/loader_tags.py` in the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/dcb8f00d06eec99072b78d54215c9a3dc04acb99/django/template/loader_tags.py#L88):

```
self.blocks = {n.name: n for n in nodelist.get_nodes_by_type(BlockNode)]}
```

When the `{% extends %}` is being rendered, it fetches all block nodes from the template directly and stores them for rendering when the parent comes across those `block`s. Whether those blocks in the child were inside conditionals or not isn't considered.