# How to check if django template variable is defined?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django template which is used from many views. The template has a block for messages used to notify user of anything that should take their attention. Whether a message is sent or not depends on the views. Some views may send a `message` variable to the template while others may not.

```
view_1:
    message = "This is an important message"
    render_to_response("my_template.html", 
                       {'message':message, 'foo':foo, 'bar':bar},
                       context_instance = RequestContext(request))

view_2:
    message = "This is an important message"
    render_to_response("my_template.html", 
                       {'foo':foo, 'bar':bar},
                       context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In the template, I check for the `message` variable and include the block as below:

```
base_template.html:
    ....
    {% block main_body %}
         {% block messages %}
         {% endblock %}
         {% block content %}
         {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    ....

 my_template.html:
     {% extends base_template.html %}
     ....
     {% if message %}
          {% block messages %}
              <div class='imp_msg'>{{ message }} </div>
          {% endblock %}
     {% endif %}
     ...
```

Problem is that even if view_2 does not pass a message, the final html is rendered with `<div class='imp_msg'></div>` -- basically an empty div.

Since that CSS is designed to give a light_red background to messages, what I see is an empty light_red bar on the top of the page.

I also tried: `{% ifnotequal message None %}`, `{% ifnotequal message '' %}`, tried setting the `message` to `None` or `''` explicitly, but does not seem to help.

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to switch your `{% block %}` and your `{% if %}`

```
{% block messages %}
    {% if message %}<div class='imp_message'>{{ message }}</div>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Colleen. That worked. Could you please explain though why the other way didn't? I just felt it was logical to include the block only if the message existed.

Comment: I *think* it's because you have `{% block messages %}` in your base template, and the django template rendering engine takes that and looks for, and injects, that block wherever it's extended, and ignores any `if`s or anything else around it. That being said, I can't swear to you that an `{% if %}` around a `{% block %}` would ever work-- I've never tried it, so I don't know either way. It could be that it never works, and that's the primary problem, not that you have `{% block messages %}` in your base.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942797/why-cant-i-nest-a-block-tag-inside-an-if-tag makes it sound as if it's the former. I think if your `{% if %}` were in base, then, it would work. Or if the block was not in base.

Comment: What about if 'message' were 0? Maybe you want to show the value 0, then you will have to use `{% if messages != None %}`

Answer (score 45):

To check, in an if statement, you need to compare the value to `None`, like this:

```
{% if some_missing_var is None %}
   // code here if some_missing_var exists
{% else %}
   // code here if some_missing_var does not exist
{% endif %}
```

In other cases ([from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled)):

> Generally, if a variable doesn’t exist, the template system inserts the value of the engine’s `string_if_invalid` configuration option, which is set to `''` (the empty string) by default.

I tried some of the other answers, and they didn't work until I read the docs on how invalid variables are handled and the above was made clear.

Comment: This worked great for me. In my use case, I was getting a list of results from a search and it was failing if I did `{% if result %}` even if `result` was defined but empty. I wanted it to pass when `result` was defined and fail when result was not defined. For empty `result`, I wanted to display another message. Checking for `None` worked great.

Comment: I must be missing something, because on the face of it that if/else makes absolutely no sense! What if some_missing_var exists and is NOT None? I imagine that would generally be the case, because after all if a variable is present then the chances are the caller would have set it to something!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to litter your logs with `KeyError` when there is no variable in the template context I recommend to use templatetags filters.

In `myapp/templatetags/filters.py` I add:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def var_exists(context, name):
    dicts = context.dicts  # array of dicts
    if dicts:
        for d in dicts:
            if name in d:
                return True
    return False
```

In html template:

```html
{% load filters %}
...
{% var_exists 'project' as project_exists %}
{% if project_exists %}
  ...
{% endif}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works perfectly, thanks!