# How to skip if empty item in column in Django DB

Tags: python, django

I;m new to learning Django and ran into a small issue:
I'm working on a product display page where some products are in a subcategory. I want to be able to display this subcategory when needed but I do not want it to show up when unused. Right now it will show up on my page as 'NONE' which I do not want.
How do I fix this?

My model looks like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.category_name} {self.sub_category}"
```

On my webpage I use the `{{category}}` in a for loop to display the different categories. Unfortunately is shows 'NONE' when there is no subcategory.

I have tried the following:

```
{% for category in categories  %}
<p>
    {% if category.sub_category == "NULL" %}
        {{category.category_name}}
    {% else %}
        {{category}}    
    {% endif %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share the `__str__` method....

Comment: Have you checked on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924865/how-to-check-if-django-template-variable-is-defined

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 
def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.category_name} {self.sub_category}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is `NULL` at the database side, it is `None` at the Django/Python side, so you can work with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
<p>
    {% if category.sub_category is None %}
        {{ category.category_name }}
    {% else %}
        {{ category }}
    {% endif %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But instead of that, it makes more sense to fix this in the model itself:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.sub_category is None:
            return self.category_name
        else:
            return f'{self.category_name} {self.sub_category}'
```

This simplfies rendering to:

```
{% for category in categories %}
<p>
    {{ category }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!
Fixed the issue and learned something new. Thanks a lot!